# let variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function formatToStandardizedDate(from, to){

    const from_date = moment(from);

    if(to){
        let to_date = moment(to);
    }else{
        let to_date = null;
    }
}

console.log(formatToStandardizedDate("2017-04-19 00:00:00",null))
```

What's wrong with my code above? if `to` is null it at least assign a null to `to_date` but I got error of `to_date` of undefined error. Why?

Comment: with let you can't use same names of var.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

Comment: You'd need to define the `let` outside of the block if you want to use it outside the block.

Comment: Where are you using `to_date`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use same variable names with let keyword. It will throw errors if you try to do this.

---

Instead you have to use ternary operator:

```
let to_date = to ? moment(to) : null;
```

or declare it once above in the function and update the variable

```
function formatToStandardizedDate(from, to){
    const from_date = moment(from);
    let to_date = null; // initialize the variable with null
    if(to)
      to_date = moment(to); // <---here update the variable with new value.
}
```

<sub>*Updated as per JaredSmith's comment and that seems good.*</sub>

Comment: But then it might as well be a `const`.

Comment: but i guess constants can't be updated to new values.

Comment: Note that the else clause is totally unnecessary, you could just initialize `let to_date = null;` and only change it if the second parameter is truthy `if (to) to_date = moment(to);`. I still prefer your ternary example in any case.

Comment: @JaredSmith totally agree with you.